# Long term behavior of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion. The objective is to prove that 
\begin{align*}
\limsup_{t \to \infty} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} = \infty.
\end{align*}
By the scaling property of Brownian motions. It can be shown for $K \in (0,\infty)$ that
\begin{align*}
& P( B_n > K \sqrt{n}\ \  \text{ i.o.}) \\
&\geq P(B_1 > K ) \\
&>0.
\end{align*}
Now, I want to work towards the result saying that $B_n = \sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ where $X_k = B_k - B_{k-1}$ of independent random variables and using subsequently the *Kolmogorov 0-1 Law*.

However for me it is unclear how to use the *Kolmogorov 0-1 Law* to obtain a satisfactory result. For me the *Kolmogorov 0-1 Law* is about a sequence of independent $\sigma$-algebras $(F_n)_{n \geq 0} \in \mathcal{F}$. Then for any event $F \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty G_n$ one has either $P(F)=0$ or $P(F)=1$, where $G_n = \sigma(\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} F_k)$. How to apply this theorem?

Comment: The equivalence $$\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k>K\ \text{i.o.}\iff\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=N+1}^nX_k>K\ \text{i.o.},$$ valid for every $N$, shows that the event $$\left\{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k>K\ \text{i.o.}\right\}$$ is indeed asymptotic for the sequence of independent sigma-algebras $(\sigma(X_n))$.